# Non-binary tree finding leaf nodes (C#)

Tags: c#, data-structures

```
           Child c1 = new Child();
            c1.name = "c1";
            c1.Isleaf = false;



            Child c2 = new Child();
            c2.name = "c2";
            c2.Isleaf = true;



            Child c11 = new Child();
            c11.name = "c11";
            c11.Isleaf = true;


            Child c12 = new Child();
            c12.name = "c12";
            c12.Isleaf = false;


            Child c121 = new Child();
            c121.name = "c121";
            c121.Isleaf = true;

            c12.Children = new List<Child>() { c121 };
            c1.Children = new List<Child>() { c11, c12 };

            Parent p = new Parent();

            p.name = "P1";

            p.Children = new List<Child>() { c1, c2 };
            List<Child> leaves = new List<Child>();

enter code here
```

I implemented finding leaves as following using Queue

```
static public void FindLeavesQueue(Parent p, List<Child> leaves)
{

    if (p.Children == null) return;

    var toVisit = new Queue<Child>(p.Children);

    while (toVisit.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = toVisit.Dequeue();
        if (current.Isleaf)
            leaves.Add(current);

        if (current.Children != null)
        {
            foreach (var child in current.Children)
            {
                if (child.Isleaf)
                    leaves.Add(child);
                else
                {
                    foreach (Child c in child.Children)
                       toVisit.Enqueue(c);
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
enter code here
```

But in my application this is running very slow. Because tree is really huge and database transactions are involved.
What is the best way to have it faster?
Thanks

Comment: well there are no databases in the code you show, so cant comment on that, and whats 'really huge' and whats 'very slow'

Comment: you would be much better off with a recursive descent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recursive descent is simply and faster, no copy of stuff to queues.

```
static public void FindLeaves(Parent p, List<Child> leaves)
{

    if (p.Children == null) return;
    foreach(var child in p.Children)
    {
          if(child.IsLeaf)
             leaves.Add(child);
          else
             FindLeaves(child, leaves);
    }

}
```